How to make div at right side of horizontally justified (centered) element. In Tailwind or CSS
How to make this to be exact:-

In the above there is a div justified at the center, and then another div next to it. The width of both the div's changes with animation and buttons.


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="flex justify-center">

  <!-- This is unneeded extra placeholder -->
  <div class=" bg-blue-300 grow"></div> 
  
  <!-- center content whose width is not determined -->
  <div class="py-10 bg-yellow-300">Center Me</div>
  
  <!-- right content whose width is not determined -->
  <div class=" bg-blue-300 grow">
    <div>Needs to be in right of center</div>
    <div>TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
  </div>
  
</div>




How you want to approach this problem you can use grid or flex if you want

anything will be fine, but my preference is flex

Not sure if there is another way, but i can only think of position: absolute for the right div. The only draw back i can think of is it affected by screen's width, not much but still can be a big problem.

add one more on the left and display: none for it

Expand on my comment above. Basically the side div will be position absolute inside the centered div (so it can be side by side and easier to control spacing between the two).
Also the draw back is if the centered div too big, it will push the side out of view/create the hoz scroll. Can be fix with some media query though.


* {margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box}

.big_div {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.centered_div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

.side_div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(100% + 15px);
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 15px;
}
<div class="big_div">
    <div class="centered_div">
        Centered Div
        
        <div class="side_div">
            Side Div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




Best way you can use it using absolute inside relative container because you have content that push element inside it or instead of using flex you can use grid instead to press content
Solution using flex:


   <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="flex justify-between relative">

  <!-- This is unneeded extra placeholder -->
  <div class="bg-blue-300 grow"></div> 
  
  <!-- center content whose width is not determined -->
  <div class="py-10 bg-yellow-300">Center Me</div>
  
   <div class="bg-blue-300 grow"></div> 
  
  <!-- right content whose width is not determined -->
  <div class="bg-blue-300 absolute right-0 h-full">
    <div>Needs to be in right of center</div>
    <div>TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
  </div>
  
</div>



Using grid


   <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-3">

  <!-- This is unneeded extra placeholder -->
  <div class="bg-blue-300"></div> 
  
  <!-- center content whose width is not determined -->
  <div class="py-10 bg-yellow-300">Center Me</div>
  
  
  <!-- right content whose width is not determined -->
  <div class="bg-blue-300">
    <div>Needs to be in right of center</div>
    <div>TEXT TEXT TEXT</div>
  </div>
  
</div>



in the end it up to you how would you approach this

is there any way we can get rid of the extra space between the center div and right div's text in the first answer. I want that text right next to the center div. And for the gird answer, is there any way, I can make the center div's width to fit content inside it, I don't want it to have extra width.

@SidharthBajpai for first example using flex you can simply move the right attribute as you need and for grid please read fit-content it will save you hour of debugging
